# Status bar color iOS

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar, uistatusbar

Somehow, no matter the query or number of answers I come across, I can't find one person who can say how to set the status bar color in iOS using Swift 3. I've seen all the suggestions where you add:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

but the thing is, I don't want a transparent status bar. I want a *specific* hex color for the status bar color.

Comment: "I don't want a transparent status bar" Tough luck. It _is_ transparent (in recent versions of iOS). Once you accept reality, you can start accepting workarounds.

Answer (score 3):

Here is [Apple Guidelines/Instruction](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/status-bars/) about status bar change. Only Dark & light (while & black) are allowed in status bar.

*Here is - How to change status bar style:*

If you want to set status bar style, application level then set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `NO` in your `.plist' file.

if you wan to set status bar style, at view controller level then follow these steps:

1. Set the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `YES` in the `.plist` file, if you need to set status bar style at UIViewController level only.
2. In the viewDidLoad add function - `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate`
3. override preferredStatusBarStyle in your view controller.

-

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Set value of .plist according to status bar style setup level.
[image]

You can set background color for status bar during application launch or during viewDidLoad of your view controller.

```
extension UIApplication {

    var statusBarView: UIView? {
        return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
    }

}

// Set upon application launch, if you've application based status bar
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return true
    }
}


or 
// Set it from your view controller if you've view controller based statusbar
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

}
```

Here is result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t an API to set the color of the status bar’s content; if you’d like one, you should file an enhancement request [here](https://bugreport.apple.com). If you want to change the color of the background *behind* the status bar, put a view with that background color at the top of your app’s window.

Comment: Upvote for putting a colored view below status bar. Sadly that was my way of doing it.